# Access to registry seems to be different from different sources

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to add a registry key in my C# code under

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\blabla
```

I want the user to be able to send any file to my application, kind of like `Open with UltraEdit` or so.

I don't have administrator rights and the users won't have administrator privileges, too.

1. If I am doing that in my C# code as posted below, I get a

   > System.UnauthorizedAccessException

   ```
   Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\*\\shell\\blabla", null, "FastSearch");
   string path = Application.ExecutablePath;
   Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\*\\shell\\blabla" + "\\Command", null, path + " \"%1\"");
   ```
2. If I run *Regedit* and attempt to do it manually myself, I get a similar error:

   > Error! Key could not be created. Error when writing to the registry.

BUT, if I double click a *.reg file that attempts to write the SAME KEY, everything works!

So why is that?

And do I have a chance to get this done through code?
Or should I just change my code to run that *.reg file?

**UPDATE:**

Actually the *.reg file did not write the SAME KEY as stated above, but

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\blabla
```

I didn't notice that. It seems as anything added under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes*\shell\blabla** is also added to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\blabla**. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` for shell extensions nowadays because this is in real `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` which requires administrative privileges because all changes there affect all user accounts. Add the shell extension instead to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` which can be modified without administrative privileges. UltraEdit registers its shell extension also only for current user as every user using a computer should have the choice to use the shell extension or do not use it.

Comment: Wow, that was actually the reason! The .reg file didn't attempt to write THE SAME KEY, it attempted to write to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\blabla". I didn't notice that, because after executing the reg file I checked "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\*\\shell\\blabla" and found it there!! Sorry for causing that confusion. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the problem is solved already and the reason for successful import of *.reg file was found out also in the meantime  in comparison to C# code, here is a complete answer for this question.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx) (short **HKCR**) as described by Microsoft shows file name extension associations and COM class registration information which are effective for the current user.

The real locations in registry for those keys are:

- **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes** (short **HKLM\Software\Classes**) containing the defaults for all users using a machine and
- **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes** (short **HKCU\Software\Classes**) containing the user specific settings which override the default settings from **HKLM\Software\Classes**.

A registry write to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** is always redirected to **HKLM\Software\Classes**. A write access to any key in **HKLM** requires administrative privileges which is the reason for the error message.

Microsoft recommends to write directly to either **HKLM\Software\Classes** or to **HKCU\Software\Classes** depending on changing the defaults or the effective file associations for the current user.

Write operations to keys under **HKCU** do not require administrative privileges.

**HKCR** should be used only for reading currently effective settings for file name extension associations and COM class registration information and not for adding or changing them.